# __sync_bool_compare_and_swap - return value if oldval and newval are same

Tags: multithreading, gcc, compare-and-swap

the documentation does not say what happens when the expected `oldval` and the `newval` is the same.  Following is from the gcc doc:

*The “bool” version returns true if the comparison is successful and **newval is written**.*

So if the newval and oldval is the same, effectively there is no write. So will following code *always* returns true if the `*ptr == 0` ?

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&ptr, 0, 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing different about the case where newval equals oldval. The newval is written if the current value equals oldval. In your case, the current value is 0, which equals 0, so it writes 0. On some processors, this write can fail even though the value being written is the same as the value already there.

Comment: on what processors will it fail?

Comment: Nearly all RISC processors (like the one in your pocket, which is probably an ARM) use load-locked+store-conditional which can fail a compare-exchange of this sort.

Comment: so what will be the return value of __sync_bool_compare_and_swap  in that case?

Comment: If the store of the 0 succeeds, then it will be true. If the store fails (e.g., another thread also wrote 0 at the same time, causing the cache line to be lost), then it will be false.

Comment: Looking at the gcc source code, [it passes false for is_weak](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2a0aa7223467b8f11e33057165715803c64b5f0e/gcc/builtins.c#L5912), so this is a strong compare-exchange, and the second case won't happen. (The compiler will auto-retry in the case of a write conflict until an iteration occurs with no conflict.) So even on RISC systems, it will always return true.

Comment: "So if the newval and oldval is the same, effectively there is no write." But the function documentation doesn't say "if newval is effectively written." newval is indeed written. The effect may be the same as if it weren't written, but it is written by the abstract machine.